# how to configure squid to never look into sever if cache file is not older than let's say 3h?

Tags: squid

So I need squid to be completely silent to some pages when these pages are cached, and I also need to cache everything from these domains. Silent that is not even send request to check if particular resource was updated. I need this only for specific domain, not whole net.

I am very new to squid.

The reason is that Im writing something that needs often to query remote servers so it could be taken as a malware on my system or a conscious attempt to break security on that server. So  I need to perform these connections locally. It wouldn't have much sense if my proxy would try to connect to remote server for every my local request even for checking if there are modifications to cached files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`refresh_pattern`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/) directive.